# Would you get the same hash map through the double hashing algorithm & the quadratic hashing algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, hash, double-hashing

Suppose for a Double Hashing Algorithm,

```
 h(k) = k mod 29  & h'(k) = 13 - k mod 13
```

and for a Quadratic Hashing Algorithm

```
 h(k) = k mod 29  & h'(k) = h(k) + (j * j)
```

Where the size of the array is the same (ex. 29 for both algorithms).

Would you be able to construct identical hash tables using both these algorithms separately?

If you were to output each individual key (with their respective values) from a bucket array, would the keys (from both algorithms) be in the same spot in the bucket array? Or would the keys be sorted differently?

Comment: What are you asking? That the elements would be in the same positions?

Comment: @Caleth Yes, would the elements be in the same position?

Comment: Are you asking whether it is possible to find such j that all k would end up in the same place in the table, or is it possible to have a situation for some sequence of numbers k and some j?

Comment: Different hashing functions would give you different positions for a given element (that's why they are different)

Comment: @unlut I've edited my answer to make it more clear, hopefully.

Comment: @Sarmon: Consider these two hashing functions: `h(k) = k mod 29` and `h(k) = k mod 129`. Same result for `k < 29`, even though the functions are different

Comment: In general? Or for some specific collection of keys?

Comment: @Useless In general.

Comment: How does the size of the array (15) come in? Does it limit k or j?

Comment: @vll Sorry, the size of array should have been 29, since it's h(k) = k mod 29, not k mod 15.

Comment: @vll you only considered `k < 29`. My comment is about the mathematical definition of a function (equal functions = equal output for every input). f = g only if you can write f as g

Comment: @AngoMango what do you mean by `h'` ?

Comment: @Sarmon `h'` is just the function name in terms of k.

Comment: Yes: if there are no collisions -- since the first hash function seems to be the same in both cases.  Probably not if there are collisions, but that may depend on a combination of what the key values are and what the two second hash functions do and what spare slots are available when a collision occurs.  [What is the purpose of this question ?]

Comment: @ChrisHall I'm working on both algorithms, and receiving similar results had worried me. I'm still on the edge of whether it should actually be the same, but I may have done something wrong anyways.

Comment: I'd try with many `k` the same, and/or the same _mod 29_ and see what the secondary hashing does.

Answer (score 0):

If `j` is a constant, then no. There is no constant, `j` that will satisfy the equality:

```
13 - k mod 13 == (k mod 29 + (j * j)) mod 29
```

For all values of `k`.

By the way, `13 - (k mod 13)` is a terrible secondary hashing function. That limits your secondary hash to the range 0 through 12. You'll end up with many more keys in the first 13 buckets than in buckets 13 through 28.

Come to think of it, because `13 - (k mod 13)` limits results to values 0 through 12, and `(k mod 29 + (j * j)) mod 29` can generate values in the range 0 to 28, the answer is no.